# TVirtuailStringTree text and image Alignment

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

i am drawing text and image in `tvirtuailstringtree` as following in `onbeforecellpaint` event

```
begin
Textrectplace := NewRect;
Textrectplace.Left := Textrectplace.Left + 2;
Textrectplace.Width := 24;
Textrectplace.Height := Data.image.height;
Textrectplace.Top := Textrectplace.Top;
Textrectplace.Bottom := Textrectplace.Bottom;
xOfftext := Textrectplace.Left + Textrectplace.Width + 4;

yOfftext := Textrectplace.Top - 3 + ((Data.image.height - TargetCanvas.TextHeight('H')) div 2);
TargetCanvas.font.color := clgray;
TargetCanvas.font.Size := 10;
TargetCanvas.TextOut(xOfftext, yOfftext, Data.text);
end;

end;


begin
imgrect:= Textrectplace;
imgrect.Left := imgrect.Left + 150;
imgrect.Width := 24;
imgrect.Height := 36;
imgrect.Top := imgrect.Top - 6 + ((Data.image.height - TargetCanvas.TextHeight('H')) div 2);
imgrect.Bottom := imgrect.Bottom;

TargetCanvas.Draw(imgrect.Left, imgrect.Top, Data.image);
end;
```

I have one problem in text and image alignment I wanted the text to be aligned to left and that part is  handled . the image has align problem I wanted to make it aligned to the Right with the text without `textoverflow` currently if the node has short text its all good and the image showing correctly with the text .  but if the text is too long its `overflow` the image .

here is example image

[image]

in the image example It shows how the long texted node looks like and how it should be if the text is too long and the list width is small for the alignment of the image with text it should show **I am long nod...** until the list become bigger then show the full text which is **I am long node text** how can I achieve that

Updated Code

```
procedure TForm1.virtuailtreeBeforeCellPaint(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
      TargetCanvas: TCanvas; Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex;
      CellPaintMode: TVTCellPaintMode; CellRect: TRect; var ContentRect: TRect);
var
Data: ^PnodeData;
NewRect: TRect;
Textrectplace: TRect;
imgrect : TRect;

begin



if not Assigned(Node) then
begin
exit;
end;

Data := virtuailtree.GetNodeData(Node);

NewRect := CellRect;




//text
begin
Textrectplace := NewRect;
Textrectplace.Left := Textrectplace.Left + 2;
Textrectplace.Width := 70;
Textrectplace.Height := 30;
Textrectplace.Top := Textrectplace.Top;
Textrectplace.Bottom := Textrectplace.Bottom;
TargetCanvas.font.color := clgray;
TargetCanvas.font.Size := 10;
DrawText(TargetCanvas.Handle, pChar(Data.text), Length(Data.text)
, Textrectplace, DT_End_Ellipsis );
end;

end;

//right image that should be stay at the right position 


begin
imgrect := Textrectplace;
imgrect.left := imgrect.left + 150;
imgrect.Width := 24;
imgrect.Height := 36;
imgrect.Top := imgrect.Top - 6 + ((30 - TargetCanvas.TextHeight('H')) div 2);
imgrect.Bottom := imgrect.Bottom;


TargetCanvas.Draw(imgrect.left, imgrect.Top, Data.image);
end;




end;
```

Comment: What is `NewRect`, where and how does it receive its value? What is the meaning of `XOffText` (why is it given a value beyond `TextRectPlace`. Have you considered using `DrawText()` instead of `TextOut()`?

Comment: Use the textwidth function to see if the text is too long, then shorten it character by character until it fits.

Comment: NewRect is a `TRect` var . xofftext to make the drawing text centered with an image , drawtext will make any difference ?

Comment: @Dsm Shorten is a part of the idea but what I couldn't figure out is how to show the full text if the list size come bigger

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but if you are saying when the component resizes then it is automatic because the cell repaints and the function will be called again.

Comment: Ah - but don't permanently shorten the text - just use a temporary copy for painting purposes and shorten that.

Comment: @TomBrunberg I used drawtext to shorten the text and it helps Thanks for that reference

Comment: @Dsm using drawtext is shorten the text as following  `DrawText(TargetCanvas.Handle, pChar(Data.text), Length(Data.text)
, Textrectplace, DT_End_Ellipsis );`

Comment: @Dsm but on resizing the text still shorten I use splitter to resize

Comment: I don't see what difference using a splitter makes. Your code is not complete. Please give us a small, complete example that illustrates your problem. Then we can try it in our compilers to see if we can see what your problem is.

Comment: I assume you are using owner draw?

Comment: @Dsm Updated Code added

Comment: Yes, Raelpaul, that's exactly what I meant with `DrawText()`. Do you have 1 or more columns? Which column are we now speaking about? Have you aligned (e.g. `alLeft`) the `TVirtualStringTree` and are you then using the `TSplitter` to resize the `TVirtualStringTree`? If yes, then adjust the size of `TextRectPlace` accordingly. But this raises the question what will you do with the image? I  guess move it.

Comment: I have only one column that contain every thing text and image , the point of resizing is to move that image exactly the same way as column

Comment: So, `TextRectPlace.Right := ItemRect - imgRect.width; imgRect.Left := TextRectPlace.Right;`

Comment: Sorry, I looked at wrong paint stage. In my previous comment replace `ItemRect` with `CellRect`.

Comment: @TomBrunberg That's totally a solve . Thank you very much please answer the question so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To shorten the text to fit within a `TRect` you can use the WinApi [`DrawText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162498(v=vs.85).aspx) function, with `DT_END_ELLIPSIS` format specifier.

To adjust the space for text when the `TVirtualStringTree` is resized (e.g. with a `TSplitter`) simply use:

```
TextRectPlace.Right := CellRect - imgRect.width;
imgRect.Left := TextRectPlace.Right;
```

Answer (score 0):

This example shows how to make the column cell and heading text aligned to the left and cell image to the right :

```
VirtualStringTree1.Alignment := taLeftJustify;
VirtualStringTree1.BiDiMode  := bdLeftToRight;
VirtualStringTree1.Header.Columns[ 0 ].Alignment := taRightJustify;
VirtualStringTree1.Header.Columns[ 0 ].BiDiMode := bdRightToLeftNoAlign;
VirtualStringTree1.Header.Columns[ 0 ].CaptionAlignment := taRightJustify;
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61izJ.png)